# How to produce a compiler error about define

Tags: c++

In `Item 2: Prefer consts, enums, and inlines to #defines` of Scott Meyers' favorite book `Effective C++`, it refer a compiler error. I want to produce a program which leading to this error. After thinking over for a long time, I can't find it.

```
#define ASPECT_RATIO 1.653
```

> the symbolic name ASPECT_RATIO may never be seen by compilers; it may
>   be removed by the preprocessor before the source code ever gets to a
>   compiler. As a result, the name ASPECT_RATIO may not get entered into
>   the symbol table. This can be confusing if you get an error during
>   compilation involving the use of the constant, **because the error mes-
>   sage may refer to 1.653, not ASPECT_RATIO**. If ASPECT_RATIO were
>   defined in a header file you didn’t write, you’d have no idea where
>   that
>   1.653 came from, and you’d waste time tracking it down.

I can think of `int *p = ASPECT_RATIO` OR `int a[ASPECT_RATIO]`, but they produce error like these. They do not contain **1.653**

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’
error: size of array ‘p’ has non-integral type ‘double’
```

Can anybody think out some examples as Scott considering?

Comment: `We may encounter an compiler error that refer to 1.653 but ASPECT_RATIO.` can you fix that sentence please? I'm sure that is not exactly what the book says

Comment: Compiler messages are implementation specific. It seems that your compiler will not complain about the literal value, but about its type. Anyway, asking for the exact syntax of a compiler message is a bit meaningless.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I'm sorry, I can only find a Chinese version of Effective C++. Now the sentence may express the correct idea.

Comment: @rodrigo I think the ability to produce a compiler error will help us to avoid those errors and debug. What's more, it is an interesting thing.

Comment: The compiler error you mention makes no sense, grammatically. That makes it quite impossible to try and produce it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the problems with macros is that they are replaced "before the compiler gets to see it", so if you use `ASPECT_RATIO` in some incorrect way, it won't say that `ASPECT_RATIO` is wrong, but that the value `1.653` is wrong. This is what this statement refers to.

For reference, the exact phrase in the 3rd Edition on page 13 is

> "This can be confusing if you get an error during compilation involving the use of the constant, because the error message may refer to 1.653, not ASPECT_RATIO." (any typos are mine!)

Exactly what error messages you get from what usage will depend on the compiler - the C++ standard does not explain what errors should be produced, just that the compiler should give some sort of error for certain constructs. If the compiler says "Error 11", "Array index can not be floating point value" or "You are an idiot using ASPECT_RATIO as an index to an array" is entirely up to the compiler vendor.

Comment: So some compilers may produce `error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’`, someone may produce `error: assign 1.653 to variable p with type int*`. It all depends.

Comment: @qingfeng And some compilers may produce an error message of `error: assign ASPECT_RATIO to variable p with type int*`.  It's possible for a compiler to keep track of the macro name (although I don't think that many do).